# git won't resolve my avahi hostname

Tags: ssh, git, domain-name-system, bonjour, avahi

I'm trying to do git remotes on my local network using avahi:

```
git clone ssh://josh@west.local:test.git
```

Git is complaining:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname west.local:: Name or service not known
```

Yet I can ssh to `west.local` without problems. And regular lookups succeed:

```
$ host west.local
west.local has address 208.68.139.38
Host west.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

In case it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, and west.local is an OS X machine using Bonjour.

How can I get git to talk to west.local, short of hard-coding something in `/etc/resolv.conf` (which ruins the point of zeroconf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an URL syntax issue. If you want to use a repository path relative to the home directory on the remote machine, use one of the following forms:

```
git clone ssh://josh@west.local/~/test.git
git clone josh@west.local:test.git
```

Mixing them and using ‘:’ after the host name in the full `ssh://` form does not work.

Comment: Gaaaah. I'm an idiot! Yes, that works wonders. Sigh. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no hands-on experience with zeroconf. How about creating an alias?

`alias gitclone="git clone ssh://josh@$(host west.local | awk {'print $NF'}):test.git"`